# (Linq)Dictionaries: Except not returning a Dictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, linq, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
Dim a As Dictionary(Of String, Type)
Dim b As Dictionary(Of String, Type)
```

I need what is in `a` that is not in `b` which should be something like:

```
a = a.Except(b)
```

But its giving me an Exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 
    '<ExceptIterator>d__99`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Type]]' 
to type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Type]'
```

If I use an anonymous variable it all works fine, but I need it to be strongly typed.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

p.s.: for that exception I'm guessing it has to be something related to keyValuPair, but I haven't found a way to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that `Except` returns an `IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Type))`. You could get around this by calling the `ToDictionary` extension method:

```
a = a.Except(b) _
     .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(x) x.Value)
```

But this probably would be better, since it doesn't involve creating a new dictionary:

```
For Each x in a.Intersect(b)
    a.Remove(x.Key)
Next
```

Comment: I was trying that, but for some reason when I do `x.` it's not allowing me to use `Key`

Comment: @Luis It definitely *should* work. I tested it myself just to be sure.

Comment: Well, I closed VS, reopen it, made a rebuild and... it works... Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about VB.NET, but could be here Collection was modified exception? you cannot delete something on collection, which you are modifying

Comment: @cleric That wouldn't happen in this case. You're looping over `a.Intersect(b)` which [actually creates a new `Set<T>` to enumerate](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L877-L883). Of course you could always be more careful by adding `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it - Add a ToList in the end of your expression.

a = a.Except(b).ToList